# How to compile old 32 bit c++ g++ 3.3.2 source code on debian 8?

Tags: c++, debian

Install `g++ 3.3` on `Debian 8` `=>` not available.
Compile with `g++ 4.9` and `-m32 and -g++-3.3.2 or -std=c++98 or -std=c++03`  options but it doesn't work.
There are header files missing.

Do I have to install old Debian version and old `g++/gcc` to compile this old code ?

###### NEW

I installed Ubuntu 5.10 and g++ 4. Now no header missing but problems with c++ code. C++ dialect problem ?

http://davalo.de/7847test/Source/errors_messages3.txt

m_pArray and m_MaxListSize no  declaration in the scope error:

```
template<class T, int size>
class ObjArray : public BaseObjArray<T> {
public:
    ObjArray() {
        m_pArray = m_Array;
        m_MaxListSize = size;
    }

private:
    T m_Array[size];
};
```

Comment: Why don't you just fix up the code to build with a modern compiler?

Comment: Because there are many foreign cpp files.

Comment: Which includes are missing?

Comment: http://davalo.de/7847test/Source/errors_messages.txt

Comment: How do you know the code will work in a newer compiler? Are you sure it's not just broken code? Present the [MCVE] you used to make this determination.

Comment: This code was successfully compiled in 2003,2005 with old g++ 3.3. It must be an option like  -noscope to force g++ 4.9 to do the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ubuntu 5.10 with g++ downgrade to 3.3 dit it. No error.No warnings. And all in virtual machine Vmware on win7 host, because I don't have IDE cdrom or floppy.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, the most you can do with today old stable (debian 8 jessie) is to force the install of the oldest gcc version which is 4.8.

But there are some repo containing older versions of gcc… like almost everything:

Deb (debian) [Pool main](http://archive.debian.org/debian/pool/main/g/gcc-3.3/)

or

Deb (ubuntu) [Pool universe](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/g/gcc-3.3/)

And force install of your compatible version.

What is the gap when you build with newer gcc 4.8…? What kind of errors do you have, how many? The best would be to fix the code.

Comment: I use the Release version. Makefiles in Game, in Game/ObjectDLL and in Game/Shared. Here the whole project: http://davalo.de/7847test/Source/

Comment: I try to install Debian 8, 32 Bit and only gcc/g++ 3.3 from the "Pool main" but again header files missing. http://davalo.de/7847test/Source/errors_messages2.txt

Comment: This missing files are in libc6-dev (or libc5-dev). Check if it is installed, and maybe you'll have to configure defaults path or simply include it. https://packages.debian.org/search?searchon=contents&keywords=cdefs.h&mode=filename&suite=oldstable&arch=any